# How to I mock a void service that returns values in one of its arguments?

Tags: unit-test, apexmock, dependency-injection

Let's say I have a typical fflib service class with a void method *(Application.cls omitted for clarity)*

```
public class MyService {
  public static void doStuffInSitu(String someContext, MyWrapper wrapper){
    service().doStuffInSitu(someContext,myWrapper);
  }
  private static IMyService service() {  // service factory
    return (IMyService) Application.Service.newInstance(IMyService.class);
  }
}

public class MyServiceImpl implements IMyService { // concrete impl of service

   public void doStuffInSitu(String someContext, MyWrapper wrapper) {
       // a lot of complicated stuff goes here
       wrapper.bar = 'someBarValue';  // set value in calling arg
       return;
   }
}
```

with inner type

```
public class MyWrapper {
  public String bar;
  public string foo;
}
```

all of this enclosed within some larger code path:

```
public class MyOrchestration{

   public void doOrchestration() {
     // do a bunch of stuff - set someMyWrapper.foo
     MyService.doStuff('abc',someMyWrapper);
     // do stuff that relies on myWrapper returning a value in .bar <== IMPORTANT
   }
```

with testmethod

```
  new MyOrchestration().doOrchestration();
```

Since I'm testing `doOrchestration`, i want the service it calls (`MyService.doStuffInSitu(..)`) to be mocked and return a mocked `bar` value back in its calling arg as that is the way the service was written.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the service method being mocked is a void method, you can't use the [ApexMocks](https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-mocks) `thenReturn`.  You can use the `doAnswer` method of ApexMocks. I'm assuming some familiarity with ApexMocks already.  If using [Amoss](https://github.com/bobalicious/amoss), consult its documentation.

The normal setup for apex mocking except where noted on the line marked `doAnswer`

### Test method

```
    fflib_ApexMocks mocks = new fflib_ApexMocks(); // establish mock environment
    
    //  mock and stub MyServiceImpl
    mockMyService = (MyServiceImpl) mocks.mock(MyServiceImpl.class);

    mocks.startStubbing();
    ((MyServiceImpl)mocks.doAnswer(new MockMyServiceAnswer(),mockMyService) // <== doAnswer
        .doStuffInSitu( // service returns values in its argument[1]
            (String) fflib_Match.anyObject(),
            (MyWrapper) fflib_Match.anyObject()); 
    mocks.stopStubbing();

    // Given mocks injected
    Application.Service.setMock(IMyService.class,mockMyService);

    // When code-under-test executed
    new MyOrchestration().doOrchestration();
    // then verify  -- e.g. verify mock UnitOfWork (not shown)
```

The above is saying -- that when method `doStuffInSitu` of the injected mock Service (`mockMyService`) is called with any String argument and any MyWrapper argument, return in the calling arg a value determined by the class `MockMyServiceAnswer`.

`doAnswer` takes two arguments - an object that implements `fflib_Answer` and the object where the answer should be returned in one of its calling arguments (i.e., the "answer")

### So, let's look at the class that does the answering

```
 public class MockMyServiceAnswer implements fflib_Answer { 

   public Object answer(fflib_InvocationOnMock invocation) {

     MyWrapper myWrapper = invocation.getArgument(1); // [1] is the myWrapper arg in call to doStuffInSitu
     myWrapper.bar = 'mockedBarAnswer'; // enhance the arg w/ answer
     // return is only required if mocked method is not void   

   }
 }
```

That's it - you tell Apex Mocks via .doAnswer where your answering object is and let it return a value back to the mocked `MyServiceImpl` object's relevant argument

### Notes

1. You can make your Answer class parameterized using typical dependency injection through its constructor so several test methods can mock different values answered in the `myWrapper.foo` variable thus changing the paths through `doOrchestration`'s business logic
2. If you had multiple methods within MyServiceImpl that returned values within its arguments, then you'd have multiple classes, each implementing fflib_Answer.  Your stubbing would associate each method with a different `doAnswer` Answer object.
3. You can stub multiple answers for the same method call by using matchers if the arguments passed to `doStuffInSitu` vary based on your business logic and unit test case.
4. If your method being mocked is not a void method but also modifies values back into its arguments, you can use the `.thenAnswer(..)` method. This is well covered in [Answering with ApexMocks](https://xonoxforce.wordpress.com/2017/03/31/answering-with-apex-mocks/) by Enzo Deti.
5. Of course, if void method `doStuffInSitu` returned a value rather than returning values through its argument, you wouldn't use ApexMocks `.doAnswer(..)` but instead use `.thenReturn(..)`.